# Meteor Mongo Never Returns Data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor 1.3.2.4 and Mongo 3.2 (which doesn't seem like it should have major problems using it with Meteor), when running queries (really any queries) on collections larger than ~10,000 documents, they never return, or take many minutes to return.

I have indexes on most of these fields; this is not a no-index problem (I wish).

There is no evidence of any issues in the mongodb logs, just connection accepted.  I have no mongo warnings or errors of any kind (fixed the mongo kernel warnings I had).

And the weirdest part about this is that when using the mongo cli, these queries run just fine, in a second or so.

One collection I'm running has ~500k docs and the other 15M.

What could be the issue?  I read a few places that MongoDB 3.2 should work fine with Meteor, am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, but according to [this post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/coming-soon-meteor-1-4/23260) we won't have official support for mongo 3.2 until meteor 1.4.

Comment: Yeah I saw that it's not supported but also a "it should work" type of comment. Next thing to try is 3.0 for sure

Comment: Indeed. Also I remember talking with Tim Haines a long time ago (2+ years) where he found something really similar - where docs would stop returning after X bytes of data were requested in a single fetch from the db. He found it while doing a migration, and found he had to break the requests into chunks in order to complete the task w/o the mongo driver exploding. All of this is anecdotal, but I remember the takeaway being meteor + lots of data in a fetch = bad. Sorry I don't have more details.